# ClientProtocolException when calling createAttachment using Ektorp to interface with CouchDB

Tags: java, couchdb, ektorp

I am using [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) (Java API for CouchDB) to store documents in my CouchDB instance.  I am having trouble attaching images to documents. Every time I call `createAttachment()` it throws an `ClientProtocolException`.

Code Sample:

```
AttachmentInputStream attachment =
    new AttachmentInputStream(attachmentId,
                              fileInputStream,
                              contentType,
                              file.length());
String rev = db.createAttachment(doc.getId(), attachment));
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem using Ektorp.  I resolved the issue by passing the latest revision number into the overloaded createAttachment method (db.createAttachment(doc.getId(), **doc.getRevision()**, attachment))).  You could probably do the following:

```
AttachmentInputStream attachment = 
  new AttachmentInputStream(attachmentId, 
                            fileInputStream, 
                            contentType, 
                            file.length());
String rev = db.createAttachment(doc.getId(), doc.getRevision(), attachment));
```

Good luck!

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. I wonder what the real problem is?

Comment: I believe that under-the-covers there is actually some type of conflict exception that Ektorp doesn't handle well. Passing in the specific revision resolves the issue because it no longer has a conflicting revision to deal with.